# Translate a column with English and Dutch text to only English using GoogleTrans

Tags: python, googletrans

I have a data frame with tweets and I want to translate it to only English. The problem is that the source column has both English and Dutch tweets. I used the following code to try to translate this column:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

df_posts['text_en'] = df_posts['text'].apply(lambda x: translator.translate(x, dest='en').text)
```

I tried some other code from stack as well, but nothing worked. I did update the translator package, so I don't have the common NoneType error anymore. The error I get looks like this:

[error that needs to be solved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9fE35.png)

The source data in the "text" column from the df_posts data frame looks like this (note that this part only shows the English text that doesn't need to be translated):

[data that needs translating](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5BhP.png)

Comment: How many rows are there in your df? I think the problem might come from the googletrans requests limit and not the language you are translating from.

Comment: about 15000 with Dutch text and 3500 with English text. Do you think that this can be solved? Or is it just not possible?

Comment: i mean the other way around... the number of observations that needs to be translated is 3500, and 1500 don't have to be translated. So, I could make subsets of course and then stack them again.